# Tkinter; Toplevel in a new class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm working on a project using Python and Tkinter. I want to modularize it.

One of the main problems is that the implementation of my `Toplevel` widget is too big.

I heard that it's possible to put this widget in a new class. The problem is I don't know how.

Here is how I define my main window:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        Config(self)
```

So for my `Toplevel` widget I tried:

```
class Config(tk.Toplevel): 
   def __init__(self, main):
       tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
```

Is it the right way to do this ?

Comment: I'd love to see all the code for the main module. Are you importing other tkinter modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the right way to do it. Though, you might want to keep a reference to the window so you can call methods on it later:

```
self.config = Config(self)
```