# Toplevel displaying contents in previous frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Toplevel class `DesignWindow` which hold a 10x10 array of buttons, when I call it in the way discussed here: [Tkinter; Toplevel in a new class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957601/tkinter-toplevel-in-a-new-class) it creates the window within the last.

[image: example]

What have I done wrong? The only difference is that my 'root' window (with the menu) is a tk.Frame instead of the tk.Tk in the quoted question.

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    """Draw the main window"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background='grey')
        self.parent = parent
        self.menuscreen = MenuScreen(self)

        self.grid()

        self.menuscreen.design.grid(column=0, row=0)

class MenuScreen(tk.Frame):
    """Create the menu screen"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.design = tk.Button(command=self.create_design_window, text="Design")

    def create_design_window(self):
        self.design_window = DesignWindow(self)

class DesignWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    """Frame for design mode"""
    def __init__(self, main):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
```

EDIT Generation of the Buttons:

```
     self.btn = [[0 for x in range(10)] for x in range(10)]
        for column in range(10):
            for row in range(10):
                self.btn[column][row] = tk.Button(main)
                self.btn[column][row].grid(column=column, row=row)
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does the `MenuScreen.__init__` not need to call it's super and don't you need to pass the parent to both super constructors.

Comment: Really sorry, forgot the add the top class that actually does the rendering bit :/

Comment: Are you asking why widgets that should be in the toplevel are instead in another window? If so, you need to show us how you're creating the windows in the toplevel.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm asking. As for how I'm creating each widget it is an instance of tk.Button() I'm not sure how you 'create a window' in the Toplevel and have seen no mention of such. Perhaps you could link a resource which explains this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's enough code in your answer to know for certain, but there are definitely two bugs that I see right away.

First, `MenuScreen` isn't calling the `__init__` of it's superclass. You need to add this to `MenuScreen.__init__`:

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

Second, you aren't giving a parent to the widgets in `MenuScreen`, so they are added to the root window. You should get in the habit of always providing a parent:

```
self.design = tk.Button(self, ...)
```

You don't show how you create any widgets in `DesignWindow`, but I'm guessing you're making the same mistake. You need to make sure that all widgets have an explicit parent or they will end up in the root window.

Comment: I am following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application as a way to structure so it makes sense not to right?

Comment: @ThomasCarroll: _"so it makes sense not to"_ -- makes sense not to _what_? You must call the constructor of the superclass, and you must explicitly give every widget a parent.

Comment: I'm feeling as if I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is happening here? I have followed your advice but it gives a window with no buttons on account of the widgets not being loaded as before. I am going to try restructuring my program and see if it makes any changes.

Comment: @ThomasCarroll: there's nothing wrong with the structure, you're just failing to use tkinter properly. If you subclass a widget, you must call the `__init__` of the widget  you are inheriting from. When you create a widget, you must tell it what window is its parent. If you don't tell every widget what its parent is, it goes to the root window. If you would give a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we could perhaps be more helpful.

Comment: Okay I have edited my post so you can see how the buttons are made, is main the parent here? It seems I haven't defined a 'parent' in the Toplevel. Further, when I run the program now no widgets are displayed at all!

Comment: Right, I've gone through and given it a good thought. This was mostly a problem with the parent classes for each button, as you said, thanks A LOT for your help!